# Excel Office.js add-in no longer loads correctly on Windows 10

Tags: office-js, yeoman

I'm currently working on getting an Office.js add-in for Excel submitted to Microsoft. The add-in used to work well and still does on Mac OSX and office.com. However, it no longer works on Windows 10 (64 bit) with my desktop Excel 2016. My Excel project includes both customfunctions and task panes.

I have been using the [yeoman generator](https://yeoman.io/) to create my project and develop in Visual Studio Code. Up to last month I had no problem loading my add-in using either node.js to debug or through a manifest pointing to the location where the code is hosted. At some point (after the Nov Windows update?) it was no longer possible to run the yeoman generated projects on Windows 10. Not only does my project no longer load correctly but a cleanly generated yeoman project has the same issue. The client js in the taskpanes still runs but the customfunctions do not. I wonder if this is related somehow to system browser changes.

The only clue I have is that when debugging through node.js I see the following in the debug log

```
[14:42:07.011 UTC] Getting browser and debug protocol version via http://127.0.0.1:9229/json/version 
[14:42:07.012 UTC] Discovering targets via http://127.0.0.1:9229/json/list
[14:42:09.014 UTC] HTTP GET failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229 
[14:42:09.014 UTC] There was an error connecting to http://127.0.0.1:9229/json/version : connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229
```

I can't be sure if this is an indication of the problem or just a symptom that node.js is showing.

I would appreciate any advice on the problem. If others are still able to work with yeoman generated add-ins on recently updated Windows 10 that would be a good datapoint to know as well.

Thanks!

Comment: As fa r as I know custom functions shouldn't work at all in Excel 2016, since Office 365 with subscription >=1904 is needed, which I read as Excel 2019...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-requirement-sets

Answer (score 1):

The Edge WebView requires a configuration change to allow access to localhost.

Open a command prompt as Administrator and run the following command: 
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=”microsoft.win32webviewhost_cw5n1h2txyewy”

Alternatively, you can run this command:
npx office-addin-dev-settings appcontainer edgewebview --loopback

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately neither of these fixed my problem. No effect. Customfunctions still fail to load on Windows 10.

Comment: Please clear cache "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\". Build your Yeoman project and then try again. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Deleting the WEF folder doesn't do anything. One thing that might point to the problem is that even after deleting WEF I'm still seeing an entry for my Add-in in the **Insert** tab under _My Add-ins->Developer Add-ins_. How do I make these entries go away?

Comment: Hopefully getting closer. I'm running literally the same code/configuration on mac and on windows. On windows I see the additional line when starting the debug:

'Enabled debugging for add-in e022c7d8-e978-4a3d-b71f-2ff8f6e65172. Debug method: 0'

I've read that node debug method needs to be 'web' but something on my windows system keeps forcing it to 'native'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache may help:

1. Keep the node.js which serves your add-in running,
2. Clear everything under %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\,
3. Pick your add-in from the dropdown list Excel->Insert->My Add-ins.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24898205)

Comment: Answer revised.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the real solution but in addition to the WEF folder on the file system I found some registry keys under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF\Providers` and I deleted any provider that I couldn't justify keeping. That combined with the Monthly Office update seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks everyone for your help but seems to be some kind of registry corruption problem.